# Multiple pods in one workspace

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, xcode-workspace

I have a large workspace that I want to use a base, to create another project on top of it, using it's code. 
Instead of working directly on the code, I would like to create another project myProject, with myPodProject, so I could access their code and their pods, and add my code and pods independently.

The original structure:

```
CoreApp
|
+-- CoreApp.xcworkspace
     |
     +-- CoreProject.xcodeproj
     +-- Pods.xcodeproj
```

What I have done is to create my own workspace with my project, draged all the core projects into the workspace and pointed to the core projects with "Header Search Path".

So the new structure is:

```
MyApp
|
+-- MyApp.xcworkspace
     |
     +-- MyProject.xcodeproj
     +-- CoreProject.xcodeproj
     +-- Pods.xcodeproj
```

Till here all good.

Now, I would like to have my own pods. But it seems it is a problem having 2 Pods.xcodeproj in the same workspace.

What should I do to have this?

```
MyApp
|
+-- MyApp.xcworkspace
     |
     +-- CoreProject.xcodeproj
     +-- CorePods.xcodeproj
     +-- MyPods.xcodeproj
     +-- MyProject.xcodeproj
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** It is possible to have two "Pods.xcodeproj" in the same **workspace**, but is impossible to have those in the same **directory**.

## Subdirectory solution

If you checkout "CoreProject" into a subdirectory of "MyProject", you can execute `pod install` in both directories "MyProject" and "CoreProject". In this way, both projects can have its own "Pods.xcodeproj".

This is the file structure after doing it.

```
MyProject
├── MyProject
├── MyProject.xcodeproj
├── MyProject.xcworkspace
├── Podfile
├── Podfile.lock
├── Pods
│    └── Pods.xcodeproj
└── CoreProject
    ├── Core.m
    ├── CoreProject
    ├── CoreProject.xcodeproj
    ├── CoreProject.xcworkspace
    ├── Podfile
    ├── Podfile.lock
    └── Pods
         └── Pods.xcodeproj
```

Finally you should do following steps.

1. Open "MyProject.xcworkspace"
2. Add "CoreProject.xcodeproj" and its "Pods.xcodeproj"
3. Link "CoreProject" from "MyProject"

Don't use "CoreProject.xcworkspace" to edit "MyProject".

This is the project structure in this case.

```
MyProject.xcworkspace
|
+-- MyProject.xcodeproj
+-- Pods.xcodeproj (for MyProject)
+-- CoreProject.xcodeproj
+-- Pods.xcodeproj (for CoreProject)
```

## Sharing pods solution

If you can touch the CoreProject's Pods, the following solution is suitable.

You should create a new "Pods.xcodeproj" and share it with "MyProject" and "CoreProject".

The project structure looks like below (same as your "new structure", but pods is replaced by new one).

```
MyApp
|
+-- MyApp.xcworkspace
     |
     +-- MyProject.xcodeproj
     +-- CoreProject.xcodeproj
     +-- Pods.xcodeproj (your own)
```

This is a sample Podfile for your workspace.
If you link "CoreProject" from "MyProject", in this case, you can use "AFNetworking" in both projects, but can use "SDWebImage" only in "MyProject".

**Podfile**

```
workspace 'MyApp'
xcodeproj 'CoreProject.xcodeproj'
xcodeproj 'MyProject.xcodeproj'

target "CoreProject" do
  pod 'AFNetworking'
  xcodeproj 'CoreProject.xcodeproj'
end

target "CoreProjectTests", :exclusive => true do
  pod 'OCMockito'
  xcodeproj 'CoreProject.xcodeproj'
end

target "MyProject" do
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  xcodeproj 'MyProject.xcodeproj'
end

target "MyProjectTests", :exclusive => true do
  pod 'OCHamcrest'
  xcodeproj 'MyProject.xcodeproj'
end
```

Comment: Sounds almost good, but I wouldn't want to touch Podfile that I receive from Core. I don't want to touch their code at all..

Comment: My answer was wrong. It is actually possible to have two "Pods.xcodeproj" in the same **workspace**. But after all it is impossible to have those in the same **directory**.

Comment: So you can checkout "CoreProject" into a subdirectory of "MyProject", and add it in the workspace which is generated by your pods. This is a bit ugly but simple.

Comment: Please create a new answer with the subdirectory solution and I'll check it as correct

Comment: Thanks! Corrected the wrong description and added the new solution.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to xiongmaomaomao's answer, if your second project (in this case, let's say CoreProject) lives in another directory (separate from MyProject and your Podfile) and you want to use a pod (such as OCMockito, for unit testing) in both projects, you need to do something like this in your Podfile:

```
def mockito_shared_pod
  pod 'OCMockito', '~> 3.0'
end

target "MyProjectTests" do
  inherit! :search_paths
  mockito_shared_pod
end

target "CoreProjectTests" do
  mockito_shared_pod
  xcodeproj '../<path_to_proj_file>/CoreProject.xcodeproj'
end
```

As you can see, the important thing here is to define 2 targets for each project, and for the target associated with the project that is NOT in your MyProject / Podfile directory, you need to specify where that project is by adding the `xcodeproj` value.

The `mockito_shared_pod` definition is not necessary, but it avoids having to specify the pod twice (once in each target).

I'm posting this because xiongmaomaomao's answer was very helpful, but I needed to do it a bit differently to fit my unusual case, and maybe someone else will have the same issue as I did.